# Labuhan Lombok to Poto Tano, how to?

Tags: public-transport, transportation, indonesia, sea-travel, lombok

I am in Indonesia & I want to go from [Labuhan Lombok](https://goo.gl/maps/btLV4) (east Lombok) to [Poto Tano](https://goo.gl/maps/jzFx7) (west Sumbawa).

I'd like to know:

1. Type of transportation
2. Departure times
3. Length of journey
4. Price
5. Any usual/possible delays

[image: Picture of map from Labuhan Lombok to Poto Tano]

[© OpenStreetMap contributors](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)

Answer (score 4):

#### By ferry

The info below is from **2015**.

1. Type of transportation: ferry
2. Departure times: every hour, 24 hours a day.
3. Length of journey: 2h
4. Price: 20'000 IDR
5. Any usual/possible delays: not that I read nor heard about, when I did it, it was around noon & I jumped in a ferry that left 10 minutes later.

---

#### Resources

[lonelyplanet.com/indonesia/poto-tano](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/indonesia/poto-tano)

[wikitravel.org/en/Labuhan_Lombok](http://wikitravel.org/en/Labuhan_Lombok)

---

#### Price list

This is a picture of the price list for the ferry from Labuhan Lombok to Poto Tano. I took this photo in July 2015 at the Labuhan Lombok harbour.

[image: price list for the ferry from Labuhan Lombok to Poto Tano]

---

#### Ferry type

I'm no ferry expert but it looked pretty standard to me. It welcomes "walking passengers", motorbikes, cars, buses, trucks, anything that fits in really. I took this photo in July 2015 at the Labuhan Lombok harbour.

[image: ferry from Labuhan Lombok to Poto Tano]